# GEE spontaneously exports truncated extent?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been running a GEE script to generate seasonal, mean NDMI rasters from Landsat over a fairly large extent.  I have been using the same script for different years of imagery, each time just changing the year portion of the date filter.  It worked correctly for 2013-2017, then when I ran 2018 and 2019, the processing time went down from the normal 30-60 minutes to just 4 minutes.  The output is just a very small strip of the area I defined with boundary coordinates, however, I have not changed the boundary coordinates at all.

To trouble-shoot, I ran a nearly identical script for mean NDVI that worked correctly a couple of days ago, but this time it also produced a truncated output.

This seems to be something going wrong on the GEE side of things.  Has anyone else encountered this?  Could it be related to exceeding a quota or something?

```
//polygon area that contains the study area
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-122.203894, 43.805966],
          [-120.027298, 37.792365],
          [-114.769423, 38.723926],
          [-116.502654, 44.826888]]]);

var l8collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
.filterBounds(poly)
.filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-09-30') //month period
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER', 'less_than', 50);
print(l8collection);

// create function to mask clouds, cloud shadows, snow
var maskClouds = function(image){
  var pixel_qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  return image.updateMask(pixel_qa.eq(322));
};
var l8masked = l8collection.map(maskClouds);
print (l8masked);

// Compute NDVI
var getNDMI = function(img){
  return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference(['B5','B6']).rename('NDMI'));
  };
// map over image collection
var l8ndmi = l8masked.map(getNDMI);
print(l8ndmi);
var ndmi = l8ndmi.select('NDMI');
print(ndmi);

// calculate meanNDMI
var meanNDMI = ndmi
  .mean()
  .clip(poly);

// Export
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: meanNDMI,
  description: 'meanNDMI',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is related to the collection update that has been rolled out last year, basically they reformatted the collections a bit. Landsat 8 surface reflectance data are now actively maintained here:

```
ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
```

if you see the error in you script you can see the collection is deprecated. For additional information you can check here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/landsat#landsat-collection-structure

Comment: I hadn't thought of that.  I went with the C01 because I was able to find code snippets to for cloud masking.  I think the values in the pixel_qa band changed with C02 and I haven't figure out how to implement the cloud mask for that yet.

My code is generating the correct outputs today, so I'm not sure what the deal is.